# Display different markers depending on a selectInput field in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, markers, selectinput

I am trying to display markers on a map, which appearance would depend on a selectInput. The global idea is that the user can click on different locations on a map, searching for an ideal spot. Eventually, when the choice is ok, he validates the location by clicking on a actionbutton, displaying a marker. Without adding the icon shape, everything is working, but when I add icon properties to the addMarkers line, I get a Error in : objet de type 'closure'..., I tried several things depending on Observe, eventReactive, etc... but I'm out of ideas, any help would be much appreciated ! Thank you !

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)

icon.shapes <- c("cylindrical","spherical","cubic")

ui <- navbarPage(
      fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
            wellPanel(tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { width:300px; float:left;}'),
                      id = "leftPanel",
                      selectInput("icon_shape", "Icon shape :",
                                  icon.shapes),
            ),
            mainPanel(                          
                      tabsetPanel(
                        tabPanel("Location", leafletOutput("map")),
            )
           )
)
  )

leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%")

server = function(input, output, session) {

output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")%>%
      setView(lng = -4, lat= 52.54, zoom = 7)
  })

observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    click <- input$map_click
    text<-paste("Lattitude ", click$lat, "Longtitude ", click$lng)
    updateNumericInput(session, 'lat', value=input$map_click$lat)
    updateNumericInput(session, 'lng', value=input$map_click$lng)
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
    proxy %>% clearPopups() %>%
      addPopups(click$lng, click$lat, text)
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
    proxy %>% clearShapes() %>% 
      addCircles(click$lng, click$lat)
  })

  cageIcons <- reactive({
    
    icons(
    iconUrl = ifelse(input$icon_shape == "Cylindrical",
                     "http://www.pngmart.com/files/7/Cylinder-PNG-File.png",
                     ifelse(input$icon_shape == "Sphérical",
                            "https://img.pngio.com/sphere-d-png-sphere-3d-png-transparent-png-6604207-free-3d-sphere-png-840_614.png",
                            "https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/7-75687_shapes-clipart-cube-pink-cube-png-transparent-png.png")
    ),
    iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
    iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94,
  )
  return(icons)
  })

observeEvent(input$submit_config, {
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
    proxy %>% 
      addMarkers(input$map_click$lng, input$map_click$lat, icon=icons)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I'm trying new solutions with uiOutput. Don't hesitate to tell me if my question is not clear enough, or if you have any ideas regarding shiny options to achieve my purpose.

Comment: Well, I just found out how to solve my problem, I will answer my question soon, thanks anyway to everyone who took time reading my post !